# JNA with 32bit JVM on a 64bit OS

Tags: java, windows-7, 32bit-64bit, jna

I want to upgrade a device using a proprietary library (DLL) that I developed. The library works fine using a MFC app. However, the twist here is that we must make this work **in a browser**.

My idea was to use an applet and then call the native DLL to make this work. Everything was working fine with my test Java application. Then I tried with the applet and then nothing worked.

I've narrowed down the problem to 32bit VS 64bits JVM. Let me explain : the Eclipse IDE that I am using uses a **64bit JVM** since I am on **Windows 7 64bit**. The browser, however, uses a **32bit JVM** and that doesn't work.

The difference between the two are the parameters passed to my function. Here's some examples of the functions that the DLL exposes :

```c
bool UPGRADELIB_API Connect( const char* serverAddress, unsigned short serverPort );
bool UPGRADELIB_API Upgrade( const char* pFilePath );
```

Which are respectively matched in Java by :

```java
boolean Icon_ConnectClientNode( String serverAddress, int serverPort );
boolean Icon_Upgrade( String pFilePath );
```

My Java test GUI passes to this native lib **"192.168.x.x"** for the IP address and **50005** for the port. In *64bit*, everything is fine, as I said earlier. In *32bit*, if I print serverAddress and serverPort in C, it shows

> (null):62384

As you can see, even the port is not passed correctly.

I've been on this for a week now, I am pulling so much hair from my head that I won't have any soon... please help me!

Comment: Maybe using a long instead of a string would solve your problem since in Java, a long variable is always 64bits. Then just convert the bytes into the string format.

Comment: Install a 32-bit JVM (or even a 32-bit version of eclipse) and test on that.  Once that works properly, then you can move to the issue of making it work within the browser.

Comment: @technomage I forgot to mention, in the post, that I already tested a 32bit JVM in Eclipse. 64bit JVM in Eclipse works, but not the 32bit one. My guess is 64bit OS -> 64bit JVM = no problem but 64bit OS -> 32bit JVM = misalignment ?

Comment: The OS makes no difference; the JVM running in 32-bit will use the 32-bit subsystem of the OS (and JNA will load its 32-bit natives, and, if your native code is running, the 32-bit version of your code as well).  Look closely at whatever Windows APIs you're using to see if the docs indicate differences in behavior between 64- and 32-bit operation.  Is the serverAddress null on the Java side, or is the null value coming from some network API call made by the C code using serverAddress as input?

Comment: @technomage It's null (and the int is wrong) in the DLL function. I am not using any Windows API in the DLL, that's why it's so suprising. If I make the exact same call with the 64bit JVM, the serverAddress and port are valid and everything is okay.

Comment: Your native and Java signatures do not match; native "short" is Java "short", not "int", which will mess up your stack (and thus your incoming arguments).

Comment: @technomage I would have loved to tell you that this fixed my problem, but it did not. Changing the int to short and casting the input param did not fix nor the string or the port in the DLL. I really thought that was it...!

Comment: It certainly would have fixed at least *part* of the issue.  Ensure that you've done a completely clean rebuild of your Java code.  You might consider (for purposes of testing) removing the port argument from the native and java code to see if you can get the first string argument passed in properly.

Comment: @technomage The #define to import or export the dll. I did not test without the port yet. Will report once I do!

Comment: I understand that it's a CPP macro.  I was asking for its definition; since such XXX_API macros often encapsulate a calling convention (i.e. __stdcall), make sure you're using the proper calling convention in your JNA mapping.

Comment: @technomage I am not encapsulating another calling convention in this macro. Only the project defined one, which is cdecl. #ifdef UPGRADELIB_EXPORTS
   #define UPGRADELIB_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
   #define UPGRADELIB_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

Comment: @technomage Sorry for the delay. I tried removing the port in the parameters and it didn't work.

Comment: Change the signature to pass in 5 integer values, and pass in 0x11111111, 0x22222222, etc.  Examine the stack in your native code to determine where the stack/argument alignment is off.  One way to "print" the stack is to use the addresses of the arguments as the memory bounds to inspect (and go an extra 2-3 slots in either direction outside of the arguments).

Comment: @technomage That helped a bunch to debug, thanks! Found the error : was passing a long (that I forgot to show in my original post for some reason) and the Java long is not the same size as the C/C++ long in 32bit and 64bit. That's kinda obvious now...

Comment: @murphyalexandre Please post an answer to your own question so this can be marked as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the error : was passing a long and the Java long is not the same size as the C/C++ long in 32bit and 64bit.

Silly me.